# Ternary operator not properly handling nil data

Tags: swift

I have a JSON object I got from an API request that represents a list of articles.  These articles may or may not have a featured image so I have stored it as an optional value.  I have a class that takes the optional URL string and turns it into a UIImage, however, this crashes when the variable is nil.  To account for this, I used a ternary operator on the line that crashes that tells it to use another image in the event of a nil value, however, this does not seem to work as the app still crashes.  I've tried to wrap the line that invokes this ImageLoader class in an if statement so as to not even allow it to be called if there's a nil value, but that also doesn't work.  It seems as if the check for nil never returns true and so the crash inevitably happens.

```
List (articlesVM.entries) { entry in
  Text(entry.title!)
    .padding(15)
  if entry.visual?.url != nil {
    ImageViewWidget(imageUrl: entry.visual!.url!)
  }else {
    Image("apple")
  }
}
```

Here is the initial call of the class.  This if statement should be preventivg the call if the url is nil, but it still manages to slip through.

```
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
  var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Data, Never>()    
  var data = Data() {
    didSet{
      didChange.send(data)
    }
  }    
  init(imageUrl: String) {
    // fetch image data and then call didChange
  }
}

struct ImageViewWidget: View {    
  @ObservedObject var imageLoader: ImageLoader
  init(imageUrl: String) {
    imageLoader = ImageLoader(imageUrl: imageUrl)
    print(imageLoader.data)
  }    
  var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage: (imageLoader.data.count == 0) ? UIImage(named: "apple")! : UIImage(data: 
    imageLoader.data)!)  // This also does not check for nil properly
  }
}
```

Here is the actual ImageLoader class, and as you can see from the comment in the ImageViewWidget, the ternary operator is also failing to properly account for the nil.

Why are two different forms of nil checks not able to properly catch that nil valued optional variable, and how can I ensure that they do?

Comment: Which line is causing the issue exactly? Also, which value is nil there: `Image(uiImage: (imageLoader.data == nil) ? UIImage(named: "apple")! : UIImage(data: imageLoader.data)!)`, what does the debugger says? What if `UIImage(named: "apple")` is nil, it should crash. Why not using unwrapping? That seems like Swift <2.0 code...

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the imageLoader's data for being equal to nil, but its type is `Data` not `Data?` i.e. not an optional, so will never be nil.  Therefore teh ternary will never return true, and so will always try to load the imageLoader's data whether its there or not.

Also, I expect but can't tell as the code isn't there, that the code that fetches the image will be asynchronous, and therefore never have the image data there in time for it to be used.

You need to rethink the logic and flow of how you load your images.

Comment: Sorry- that "Data" you see in the image loader is not the data that's optional.  I'm passing into that ImageLoader data var an optional from the JSON object I'm parsing through into a list in the first snippet.  Notice that I'm checking to see if that data object is equal to 0 in the ImageLoaderWidget and in the first snippet I'm checking if its nil.  Although it is an async function returning the optional, I know I have all the data I'm going to get (i have print statements setup and they print the title of the item that crashes the app) and the check still isn't picking up the nil.

Comment: Been sat puzzling over your answer.  My point was that the Data in the image loader was not optional, but in the Ternary operator you are explicitly checking for it being optional in `imageLoader.data == nil`. As it's not an optional data type that check is pointless as it can never return true, and so will try to load the imageLoaders image, not the "apple".  I can't see any other way to interpret that line, irrespective of what is happening elsewhere in your code.

Comment: (In terms of elsewhere, I'm sure the async function will return the all the data, but will it do it in time for the rest of the code to use it - I'm not sure as I can't see the code and I've not delved into SwiftUI observers and publishers enough to understand the flow/timing)

Comment: My mistake, I uploaded a version of the ImageLoader widget with the wrong check (I'm editing the question now to show the correct check).  I originally checked a data parameter (count) if it is equal to 0 which would tell me if it's empty or not, and that too did not function as expected.

Comment: OK @JakimBeaufort, that makes it a different question.  Can you describe, or better still, add a screen grab, of the actual error(s?) and where it (they?) occurs in xcode?